# Корректная работа с очередью в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

1. Создал класс коммандой
   `php artisan queue:table`
2. Сделал миграцию командой
   `php artisan migrate`
3. Добавил реализацию в класс очереди

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Candidates;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    protected $data;
    protected $count = 0;

   
    public function __construct($user, $data)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        info($this->user);
    }
}
```

4. Добавил задания в очередь (внутри цикла)
   `ProcessPodcast::dispatch($user, $update_data_array)->onConnection('database')->onQueue('updateUserFromServices');`
5. Смотрю выполнение очереди в реальном времени командой `php artisan queue:work`.

**Вопрос:**
После срабатывания события ничего не пишет в консоле о выполненных заданий в очереди.
В бд записались все очереди, но они не выполняются, почему?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте файл env в частности поле QUEUE_CONNECTION , там должно быть указано database

Comment: Ещё нашёл как можно запустить определенную очередь командой

php artisan queue:work database --queue=queueName